# Make maven version plugin fail if it can't check for new versions

Tags: maven

I'm using the maven version plugin to update specific properties:

```
mvn versions:update-properties "-Dincludes=com.foo:my-dep:*:*:*" "-DgenerateBackupPoms=false"
```

Anyway sometimes, due a network problem, the check fails with:

> [main] WARNING org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.DefaultRepositoryMetadataManager - repository metadata for: 'artifact com.foo:my-dep' could not be retrieved from repository: central due to an error: Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/foo/my-dep/maven-metadata.xml

Nevertheless only a warning is printed and the build goes on.
Would it be possible to halt everything in this case?